# SoundCloud Widget and Flash wmode

Tags: flash, soundcloud, wmode

The SoundCloud HTML5 widget is embedded as an `<iframe>`, but it will fallback to using Flash if the browser does not support the required HTML5 components. Unfortunately, the Flash player does not have a `wmode` attribute set on it, and thus far I have been unable to get the fallback to set the `wmode` to either `transparent` or `opaque` with the code

```
<iframe wmode="opaque" width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
    src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?
    url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F42072385%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-
    awcrN&amp;color=ff6600&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;wmode=opaque">
</iframe>
```

While using the Vimeo player, setting a `wmode` attribute on the parent `<iframe>` will cause the fallback Flash to use the set `wmode`, and setting a GET parameter on the YouTube URL will cause the Flash player to use the set `wmode`. Neither of these techniques seem to work with SoundCloud. Is it possible to set the `wmode` for the Flash fallback while using the SoundCloud HTML5 player, or should I just write feature detection to handle this myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this option is not supported in the Flash widget at the moment.

Comment: Just the answer I didn't want. One can always use something like Modernizr for a feature detect and fallback to using the old Flash embed where one can specify the `wmode` attribute, but that just isn't clean as I'd like it to be. Is there are a reason this feature is not implemented with the `<iframe>` embed?

Comment: It's on our issues list, but there is no estimated time of arrival yet, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set `wmode` on `<iframe>` tag.
the flash fallback will not replace iframe with flash object, but it just uses flash as audio rendering engine.
to get transparent iframe, try `<iframe ... ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"></iframe>`